# Pass a variable from one sql script to another as parameter in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

I have two posgres sql files.
File1.sql and file2.sql.

my requirement is based on environment i need to execute some scripts in file2.sql.
And file1.sql i need to pass my environment name.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to psql with -v option and use it in a SQL script.

For example, with:

```
cat file.sql
\echo :param
```

You get:

```
$ psql -v param=param1 -e -f file.sql
param1
```

You also can try to use psql variables that are available in the same psql session.

For example with:

```
cat file1.sql
\set param 'param1'

cat file2.sql
\echo :param
```

You get:

```
postgres=# \i file1.sql
postgres=# \i file2.sql;
param1
postgres=#
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES

Answer (score 0):

Thank you pifor.

Here our issue is we passing parameter value from file1 but how read that value in file2.

In file1.sql below code exists:
\i folder1/folder2/file2.sql -v param1='123';

In file2.sql how to param1 value and assign this some variable and want to use this in file2.sql file scripts.